# How to parse and concatenate whit specific separator

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

My problem is that I have to concatenate all the text after the    *"product_link_href":*   in a huge serie of things (there are 200+ of these so I couldn't post the entire thing) like:

```
Solved snippet removed for privacy reasons
```

It's coming from an api, it's white in windows power shell, the name of the thing is response.data I'm using axios; I think this thing to the machine is just plain text, because it was green before I selected it whit   *.data* ; but I still need all the text after *"product_link_href":* concatenated, in text format and sepsarated by *","*

The code I am using is

```
axios.get('https://randomapi/' + id + '/json?api_token=examplenotrealapitoken').then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            });
```

I tried JSON.parse and stringify but nothing works.

Comment: Put the entire data in a pastebin and link it. It is stringified JSON. You need to JSON parse it, then probably map over it - but I need to see the data structure to know exactly how to traverse it.

Comment: Ok I'l try to do so

Comment: 158/5000
in JSON if a key name is repeated, only the last occurrence counts, the others are just intermediate values which are overwritten by their next

Comment: @MisterJojo's comment was enough. The code you seek is below. Let me know if it needs further mods, and feel free to accept it as the answer when it works.

Comment: @JoshWulf i'm getting error: Missing initializer in const declaration edit solved now I get error: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Try the updated code. But the data in pastebin is malformed on line 465.

Comment: Getting errror : TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: ok it was response and not resp just sint but now it gives me the error relative to the malformed json I will try whit onehte rjson work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the server is stringified JSON objects that have been concatenated with line return characters "\n".

It is not JSON parseable because it is not an array, which it needs to be, to be valid JSON.

The approach I took is to coerce it to "an array of stringified JSON objects". Since each object is shallow, there is no nesting, so the `}` character is unambiguously the end of a stringified object.

You can call `massiveJSONishString.split('}')`, and you get an array of JSON-stringified objects with the trailing `}` missing on each one.

Then you map over *that* array, and for each element, add the trailing `}` that we threw away to array-ify it, and `JSON.parse()` that string, producing an array of JSON objects.

This is the code you are looking for:

```
const textArray = res.data.split("}");

const jsonArray = textArray.map(element => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(`${element}}`);
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      product_link_href: "MALFORMED JSON"
    };
  }
});
// console.log(jsonArray);
const product_link_hrefs = jsonArray.map(obj => obj.product_link_href);
const list = product_link_hrefs.join(", ");

console.log(list);

console.log(`You're welcome!`);
```

Comment: This code works for me when I comment out the malformed JSON lines in the response.

Comment: Ok no I was wrong It works perfectly I have no words to express my gratitude; I really think that peoples like you are what makes the stack overflow community a beautiful place

Comment: Josh - can you add an introductory paragraph to explain _why_ this works? This may make it more useful for future readers.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the prompt.